# Numbers of iteration generated in a single LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I always have a question about LINQ when using it.

How many iterators have been generated for the following code (test is a List):

```
        var result = from t in test
                     where t.Length > 0 && t.Length < 5
                     orderby t[0]
                     select t;
```

As far as I know, this query is compiled as:

```
        var result2 = test.Where(t => t.Length > 0).Where(t => t.Length < 5).OrderBy(t => t[0]);
```

I examined the .NET source code and found the Where implementation simply calls the predicate function and yield the result:

```
    private static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate)
    {
        int iteratorVariable0 = -1;
        foreach (TSource iteratorVariable1 in source)
        {
            iteratorVariable0++;
            if (predicate(iteratorVariable1, iteratorVariable0))
            {
                yield return iteratorVariable1;
            }
        }
    }
```

I believe Microsoft implements OrderBy and other functions a similar way like this (OrderedEnumerable for OrderBy I suppose).

Does this mean LINQ will create multiple enumerators for this single query, which means some contents of my list will be copied several times? (The yield return statement will copy the element to a List I suppose?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your query will be compiled into single `Where` operator:

```
var result2 = test.Where(t => t.Length > 0 && t.Length < 5).OrderBy(t => t[0]);
```

And totally two enumerators will be created:

- one for filtering source by predicate
- one for enumerating filtered source to sort items

Comment: The Where enumerator makes sense.So does this means the elements will be copied 2 times?

Comment: @刀之魂 if you have source of reference types (i.e. classes) then only addresses of elements are copied. With `where` this is not a problem, because it will return only matching elements addresses one by one (you will have only one copy at a time). OrderBy unfortunately needs to have addresses of all elements to sort them

Comment: Thanks. I just wondering how Microsoft implement LINQ. This helps me a lot.